# How to implement below using Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can we implement following using streams

```
for(String str: list){
   if(someCondition(str)){
      list2.add(doSomeThing(str));
   }
   else{
      list3.add(doSomethingElse(str));
   }
 }
```

Comment: It is not the best example to use for streams. Streams are mostly for single input and single output, you have two outputs here, so it will be an abuse of streams (but doable).

Comment: can you please show how is it doable

Comment: You could do it in two seperate streams, but as krzyk said, streams are more for single input single output. but you could do something like: `list.stream().filter(s -> someCondition(s)).forEach( s -> list2.add(doSomeThing(s) );` and then `list.stream().filter( s -> !someCondition(s) ).forEach( s -> list3.add(doSomethingElse(s) );`

Comment: But if we use 2 streams it will be inefficient.

Comment: Wondering is there any better way to write above for loop ... considering clean coding practices ...

Comment: Following 'best practices' as if it were dogma is practically premature optimisation.

Comment: Stick with your solution, anything else wouldn't be readable anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to get two lists out, try this:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map
    = list.stream().collect(partitioningBy(MyClass::someCondition));
List<String> list2 = map.get(true).stream()
                        .map(MyClass::doSomething).collect(toList());
List<String> list3 = map.get(false).stream()
                        .map(MyClass::doSomethingElse).collect(toList());
```

(Or, you can use the two-arg version of `partitioningBy` with a downstream `mapping()` collector, which would have to test the condition again.)

Comment: The two-arg `partitioningBy` with downstream `mapping()` only works, if `list2` and `list3` have the same element type, i.e. `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` return the same type, which we can’t derive from the question…

Comment: Nice, however we are still looping over list twice, once for partitioning and later while mapping in list2 and list3 type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, which will only parse the list once:

```
    @Test
    void reading_the_list_once() {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Nico", "Isa", "Fran", "Percy");

        Map<String, List<String>> collect = names.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.length() > 4 ? "gt4" : "ngt4"));

        assertThat(collect.get("gt4")).containsExactly("Percy");
        assertThat(collect.get("ngt4")).containsExactly("Nico", "Isa", "Fran");
    }
```